How I can get information(like licence, updated versions) of libraries used in my Android project
I'm looking for a way to automatically scan and list all the libraries used in my Android project, along with their version numbers. I want this information to be displayed in a clear and concise format within the app itself. This will help me document the used libraries and their corresponding licenses. I'm hoping to find an automated solution that can keep the list up-to-date as I add or remove libraries from the Gradle dependencies.
I tried to use Google official plugin called play-services-oss-licenses
but its showing blank activity

Because it collects licenses only in the Release build variant

I can suggest https://docs.renovatebot.com/ quite a good one. It is a
a tool designed to automate the process of keeping dependencies up-to-date in projects. Renovate Bot scans a project's dependencies, identifies outdated ones, and automatically creates pull requests with the necessary updates. It supports various languages and platforms, integrates with popular version control systems like GitHub, GitLab, and Bitbucket, and offers customization options to manage how and when updates are applied. The documentation provides detailed information on configuring, using, and troubleshooting the bot.

Does it allow to automatically display the used dependencies in the app itself, as it was requested?

Yes, it should automatically create new PR with updated versions.

No, I meant, does it display a list of dependencies in the app for the end user to see? What kind of UI element does it create?

Sorry, I misunderstood your question, no this won't create anything in the app. It will monitor the versions and let you know with PR as soon as new versions come. At least we are using it for such purpose.

I use https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries even though the author does not support using it in a Java App, only say he supports Kotlin, it still usable you just you need to convert the Kotlin to Java from the Docs.
Note that if a dependency does not specify a license in it's pom then it still might not be picked up and needs to be manually added.

Why would Java be an issue? Their app seems to be written in Kotlin.

@Leviathan the only issue is that it is not "supported" (the author said that I should convert my Java App to Kotlin if I wanted to use his library) and the docs only tell you how to use it in Kotlin. So it works fine you just need to spend a bit more brain power to use it in a Java App.

But there is no Java app. Op's app is written in Kotlin.

I was just mentioning it to be a more complete answer and not be Kotlin specify even though it looks Kotlin specific.

Ah, I see. So the tangent on Java isn't directed at the question, it's more like additional background info. Maybe you could rewrite that part so it becomes more clear?
